# Convert _mm_shuffle_epi32 to C expression for the permutation?

Tags: x86, x86-64, sse, shuffle, sse2

I'm working on a port of SSE2 to NEON. The port is early stage and it's producing incorrect results. Part of the reason for the incorrect results is `_mm_shuffle_epi32` and the NEON instructions I selected.

The documentation for `_mm_shuffle_epi32` is on the lean side from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56f67xbk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). The [Intel](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE2&text=_mm_shuffle_epi32&expand=4690) documentation is better, but it's not clear to me what some of the pseudo-code is doing.

```
SELECT4(src, control)
{
    CASE(control[1:0])
        0: tmp[31:0] := src[31:0]
        1: tmp[31:0] := src[63:32]
        2: tmp[31:0] := src[95:64]
        3: tmp[31:0] := src[127:96]
    ESAC
    RETURN tmp[31:0]
}

dst[31:0] := SELECT4(a[127:0], imm8[1:0])
dst[63:32] := SELECT4(a[127:0], imm8[3:2])
dst[95:64] := SELECT4(a[127:0], imm8[5:4])
dst[127:96] := SELECT4(a[127:0], imm8[7:6])
```

I need help envisioning what `_mm_shuffle_epi32` does. Or more correctly, the permutation applied to the value by the immediate. I guess I need to see it as basic C and ANDs and ORs.

Given C statements and macros like:

```
v2 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(v1, _MM_SHUFFLE(i1,i2,i3,i4));
```

What does the resulting C expression look like when it's unrolled into basic C statements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no AND/OR going on, unless you need to unpack the 8bit integer holding four 2bit indices.

Make your own definition for `_MM_SHUFFLE` that expands to four args, instead of packing them.

It's something like

```
// dst = _mm_shuffle_epi32(src, _MM_SHUFFLE(d,c,b,a))
void pshufd(int dst[4], int src[4], int d,int c,int b,int a)
{   // note that the _MM_SHUFFLE args are high-element-first order
    dst[0] = src[a];
    dst[1] = src[b];
    dst[2] = src[c];
    dst[3] = src[d];
}
```

Vectors are indexed from low element = 0.  The low element is the one that stores into memory at the lowest address, but when values are in registers you should think about them as `[ 3 2 1 0 ]`.  In this notation, vector right-shifts (like `psrldq`) actually shift to the right.

This is why `_mm_set_epi32(3, 2, 1, 0)` takes its args in reverse order from `int foo[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };`.

Comment: @jww: update: put the args in an order that matches _MM_SHUFFLE, where the macro args go from MSB to LSB.  Same as `_mm_set`, opposite of `_mm_setr`.

Comment: @thc: the pseudocode in the question (quoted from the operation section in the manual) defines SELECT4 before using it.  It selects one of 4 32-bit elements, duh.

Answer (score 0):

When it's not clear what exactly some intrinsic is doing a few sample runs with simple inputs might help as well:

```
int x[] = {0,1,2,3}, y[4];
__m128i s = _mm_shuffle_epi32(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)x), _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 3, 0, 1));
_mm_store_si128((__m128i*)y, s);
printf("{%d,%d,%d,%d} => {%d,%d,%d,%d}\n", x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], y[0], y[1], y[2], y[3]);
```

[This prints:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/376aa5728d7bdbe5)

> {0,1,2,3} => {1,0,3,2}