# Practical use of psadbw and pshufd

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm, reverse-engineering, cpu-registers

I was recently looking at an assembly code which used `psadbw` and `pshufd` on xmm registers which are 128-bit register.

As per the documentation [here](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_254.html) on x86 architecture. It shows `pshufd xmm0, xmm0, imm8` But I fail to understand how we can use it practically under what cases.

Similarly, `psadbw` computes sum of absoulte differences of bytes. So, does it means like for 128bits register (16 bytes) 
.
So let's say my instruction is `psadbw xmm0 xmm5` does this do like `|1st byte of xmm5 - 1st byte of xmm0| + |2nd byte of xmm5 - 2nd byte of xmm0| + ... + | 16th byte of xmm5 - 16th byte of xmm0|` ? If not, how does that works.

Can anyone provide practical scenario ?

Comment: `psadbw` has two groups of 8. Don't you already have a practical scenario, since you encountered them in actual code

Comment: @harold -  Just confirming, so does two groups work like 
1st group = `|1st byte of xmm5 - 1st byte to xmm0 | + ....+ |8th byte of xmm5 - 8th byte of xmm0|`
2nd group =  `|9th byte of xmm5 - 9th byte of xmm0 | + ....+ |16th byte of xmm5 - 16th byte of xmm0|`

and then xmm0 results to `1st group (2 bytes) + 0 ( 6 bytes) + 2nd group(2 bytes)+ 0 (6 bytes) ` ???

Comment: Yes (I did not read too accurately), of course you could have known by reading the relevant page on that website you were using: [psadbw](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_253.html)

Comment: @harold -  Thanks, I still do not understand `pshufd` , how can one represent in a way I represent the `psadbw` ... and what does `encoding in imm8` means in the  [manual](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_254.html)

Comment: [This has a simple C equivalent for the shuffle that `pshufd` does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084379/convert-mm-shuffle-epi32-to-c-expression-for-the-permutation).   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86 for a use-case in integer horizontal sums (e.g. at the end of a loop).  `psadbw` is useful as a horizontal sum of a single register if you take the difference against 0.  (Other than the obvious use-case in image/video processing when computing SAD on 8x8 blocks.  e.g. in a motion search)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one practical scenario. The `psadbw` instruction maps to the `_mm_sad_epu8` SSE2 intrinsic, which can be found in the Chromium's fork of zlib ([code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/zlib/adler32_simd.c;l=115;drc=9fc44ce454cc889b603900ccd14b7024ea2c284c)).

Another use is in motion estimation: https://wiki.mozilla.org/SIMD/Uses/SAD