# Understanding the SIMD shuffle control mask

Tags: c, gcc, simd, avx

I'm trying to learn shuffling using this example in C [from the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html)

```
typedef int v4si __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));
     
v4si a = {1,2,3,4};
v4si b = {5,6,7,8};
v4si mask = {0,4,2,5};
v4si res = __builtin_shuffle (a, b, mask);    /* res is {1,5,3,6}  */
```

I don't understand what the `mask` does exactly? All I can find online is similar to this:

> The shuffle mask operand specifies, for each element of the result vector, which element of the two input vectors the result element gets

But it doesn't explain how? is there `AND, OR` going on? what do the numbers in mask mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mask` isn't an AND mask; the shuffle-control vector is a vector of indices into the concatenation of the source vectors.  Each result element is basically the result of `res[i] = ab[ mask[i] ]`.

SIMD shuffles are parallel table-lookups, where the the control vector (called "mask" for short, for some reason) is a vector of indices and the other inputs are the table.

Related: [Convert _mm_shuffle_epi32 to C expression for the permutation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084379/convert-mm-shuffle-epi32-to-c-expression-for-the-permutation) shows a plain C equivalent for `_mm_shuffle_epi32` (pshufd) with compile-time-constant indices.  You have a 2-input shuffle that indexes into the concatenation of a and b (in that order).

AVX1/AVX2 doesn't have a shuffle that actually does this for runtime-variable inputs, so that `__builtin_shuffle` would have to compile to multiple instructions.

[AVX512F `vpermt2d`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/VPERMT2W:VPERMT2D:VPERMT2Q:VPERMT2PS:VPERMT2PD.html) works exactly this way, though.

Comment: Thanks but I still don't understand. As an example, looking at the second mask which is a `4`, what does it do?

Comment: @Josh: it indexes element #4 from `{1,2,3,4,   5,6,7,8};` which is `5`.  Like I said, the "table" is the concatenation of the 2 input vectors.

Comment: thanks a lot, `ab[ mask[i] ]` helps picturing it, now for the final clarification, could you go through the full example with mask `4`. so now we have `5`, then what? it just places 5 in the dest index? that's it?

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
const int start = 20;
const int length = 32;
var arr1 = Enumerable.Range(start, start + length).ToArray();
var arr1LeftPtr = (int*)arr1.AsMemory().Pin().Pointer;

Vector128<int> left = Sse2.LoadVector128(arr1LeftPtr);  // left: 20, 21, 22, 23

Vector128<int> reversedLeft = Sse2.Shuffle(left, 0b00_01_10_11);  // left: 23, 22, 21, 20
Vector128<int> reversedLeft2 = Sse2.Shuffle(left, 0b11_10_01_00); // left: 20, 21, 22 , 23
Vector128<int> reversedRight = Sse2.Shuffle(left, 0b00_01_00_01); // left: 21, 20, 21, 20
```

Comment: Just for the record, this is C#, with System.Numerics intrinsics, not C with Intel's intrinsics, or GCC's native vector extensions (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html) which this question is using.  Also, your comments on vector contents appear to be written in C/C# array-initializer order, with lowest element at the left, not the place-value ordering of highest element at the left which makes vector left-shift make sense.  Your choice is a common one, but opposite of Intel's diagrams in their docs.

Comment: thanks for the comment, now I know better :-)